# Splitting and merging AST generated by ANTLR

Tags: merge, tree, antlr, abstract-syntax-tree

I have ANTLR grammar rules to parse expressions like:

`1+2*3 = 100` or `age+2*3 = 100`

My UI is tabular, as following:

age+2

---

*3 = 100

---

< 500

---

The point is the complete expression is split between header and row (eg. age+2*3=100 where age+2 is in header and *3=100 in first row).

I want to persist the partial AST in database so that I can easily show the content of header and row in UI.

With this approach there are two problems:

1) Parsing the incomplete expression in headers (eg. age+2) --> One of the solution for it is to introduce fake variable nodes which can complete the expressions (eg. age+2 = var)

2) How to combine partial ASTs in header and cell for consumption. The major problem here is, due to different priority of operators the final AST might be completely different from original ASTs of header and cell.

Comment: Well this depends on what the possible split between header and row is. Is it just text that can be split anywhere? Then good luck making partial ASTs for `age+2*3=1` and `00`. Would the example in your question be interpreted as `(age+2)*3=100`? Then it can be solved. Would it be `age+(2*3)=100`? Then you need to re-parse.

Comment: @JiriTousek: 1) Technically the text can split anywhere but I can put some constraints , if it makes thing easier. 2) age+2*3=100 need to follow BODMAS rule, it will be interpreted as age+(2*3)=100

Comment: Then I guess the most you can hope for is to do the tokenization (i.e. lexer), but you'll have to run the parser only on the complete input. I'm not sure its worth the trouble though, I'd recommend doing some benchmarks first.